# Trigger Angular change detection from console

Tags: angular

In AngularJS we were able to trigger a digest cycle by getting the ng-app element with something like

```
var scope = angular.element(element).scope(); 
scope.$apply(...);
```

I have looked all over for a solution to do this in Angular(4+) but have only found solutions that work in the app like([Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)). I need something that works from the console.

I'm sure I'm doing it wrong but trying to apply the answer on the above question didn't work. I tried many variations of this:

```
ng.probe($0).injector.view.root.ngModule.injector.get('ApplicationRef')
```

Comment: it doesn't work because you pass a string `'ApplicationRef'` instead of a reference to an `ApplicationRef` class. You need to get reference to the application class like @yurzui showed - `ng.coreTokens.ApplicationRef`. For more information on debugging, see [Everything you need to know about debugging Angular applications](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-debugging-angular-applications-d308ed8a51b4)

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I asked the same question, regarding Ivy here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59191406/3694288

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I usually do it as follows in dev mode

```
ng.probe(getAllAngularRootElements()[0]).injector.get(ng.coreTokens.ApplicationRef).tick()
```

[image]

Starting with **Angular 9** with Ivy you can call:

```
ng.applyChanges(ng.getComponent($0))
```

Where `$0` points to component's element

[image]

Comment: I keep getting back to this page so often :D thanks for response. Plus is there any shortcut ?

Answer (score 8):

**Solution 1:**
1. Click on the element (on which you want to trigger change detection) in the dev-tools Elements-Tab
2. `ng.probe($0).injector.get(ng.coreTokens.ApplicationRef).tick()`

**Solution 2:** Trigger a specific components change detector
1. Click on the element (on which you want to trigger change detection) in the dev-tools Elements-Tab
2. `ng.probe($0).componentInstance.cdRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: ng.probe($0).componentInstance.cdRef === undefined

Comment: For solution 2: Apparently, to use this*, you must inject the changeDetectorRef into your component, from @angular/core...   
( * cdRef being the locally-declared instance of changeDetectorRef )

Comment: Greate explanation dude :)

Answer (score 0):

@guati I was getting some "Failed to Load Module" error (angular 7), the error was triggered due to some changes in the routing but even when I reverted the changes, the error persisted (may be changes were not being detected) so I just restarted the development server (served the application again) and it went away.