# How to update a angular 4+ form values using console devtools?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fill a Angular 4+ form using console (devtools).

This is what I'm doing now:

```js
function fillForm(){
    let el = document.querySelector('input[ng-reflect-name="my_input"]');
    let elProbe = ng.probe(el);
    elProbe._debugContext.component.value = 'new-value';
}
```

Some references I'm trying to use (if it helps anyone):

- https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/
- [Trigger Angular change detection from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838568/trigger-angular-change-detection-from-console)

Comment: Where do you call detectChanges? Angular is very lazy it wants a kick :)

Comment: The same question: How to do $('#someId').val(somevalue) using angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options. The first one is to work with component property bound to a form and it requires manual change detection triggering. The second one is to work with the form control associated with the input and it doesn't require manual change detection.

Neither is better.

For the first option see @yurzui's answer. Here is the answer for the second option - **update the form control directly** without the need for change detection:

```
function fillForm(){
    let el = document.querySelector('input[ng-reflect-name="my_input"]');
    let elProbe = ng.probe(el);

    const NgControlClassReference = elProbe.providerTokens.find((p)=>{ 
        return p.name === 'NgControl';
    });

    let directive = elProbe.injector.get(NgControlClassReference);
    let control = directive.control;

    control.setValue('some');
}
```

In this case you don't need change detection because when you call `setValue` on the control directly it notifies `valueAccessor` about the change:

```
FormControl.prototype.setValue = function (value, options) {
  ...
  this._onChange.forEach(function (changeFn) { 
      return changeFn(_this._value, options.emitViewToModelChange !== false); });
```

where `changeFn` is a subscriber added in the `setUpContorl` function:

```
  control.registerOnChange((newValue: any, emitModelEvent: boolean) => {
    // control -> view
    dir.valueAccessor !.writeValue(newValue);
```

which calls `writeValue` on the accessor directly and it in turn writes the value into input:

```
export class DefaultValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  ...

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? '' : value;
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);
  }
```

You also might find this article useful

[Everything you need to know about debugging Angular applications](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-debugging-angular-applications-d308ed8a51b4)

Comment: Whats your context in `$0` ?

Comment: @leonardomerlin, it's `elProbe`, I've updated the details

Comment: I choose the @yurzui as a correct answer because I dont discover what referencet to put in the place of `$0` reference and nothing about the magic number "3" =/ Sorry.

Comment: @leonardomerlin, mine and yurzui's answers are different. I'm updating the form control directly and don't need to invoke change detection manually, while his solution updates the property on the parent component and requires manual trigger to change detection. The magical `3` is a reference to the `NgControl` class. You can choose whatever you like

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/rvXQ4xl6TEXchueasDS5?p=preview Are you sure that index will be 3?

Comment: no, indeed that's the problem, the index can be different. `el.value = 'some';` - yeah. I'm wondering how the form looks like, how it's bound to `value` on component

Comment: @Maximus Don't forget to refer to me :) I don't see your comment

Comment: @yurzui, improved the solution to not depend on the index :)

Comment: Yeah it will be correct now. But we can find one more solution

Answer (score 2):

Simple way of doing this could be running change detection cycle using core token for `ApplicationRef`

```
let el = document.querySelector('input[ng-reflect-name="my_input"]');
let elProbe = ng.probe(el);   
elProbe._debugContext.component.value = 'new-value';
elProbe.injector.get(ng.coreTokens.ApplicationRef).tick()
```

You can also take a look at integration tests

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts#L28-L30

I think this way we check how our component works with `NgModel` and don't call direct API on inner `NgModel` directive.

Without calling change detection we can also the following code to simulate user action

```
let valueAccessor = elProbe.injector.get(elProbe.providerTokens
                       .find(x =>x.name === 'DefaultValueAccessor'));

el.value = 'some';
valueAccessor.onChange('some');
```

But it looks very strange

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: you don't need change detection if you update the control directly

Comment: @Maximus Angular works in this way so i don't think that it is not correct

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, but for this particular case the change detection is indeed not required. See my edited answer

Comment: _You can also take a look at integration tests_ - it's a good reference, but the test is written to test `ngModel` - `'should support ngModel for standalone fields'` and `formControl` is a perfectly fine class to work with. Anyway, it'd be great to see how the form is represented in html

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste spin-off from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44973308/419956) to fill *multiple* fields at once:

```
[
  { selector: "#initials", val: "JJA" },
  { selector: "#lastName", val: "Steenbruggehoek" },
  { selector: "#email", val: "john.doe@example.org" },
].forEach(item => {
    const el = document.querySelector(item.selector);
    if (!el) { console.warn(item.selector, 'not found'); return; }
    const probe = ng.probe(el);
    const ref = probe.providerTokens.find(p => p.name === 'NgControl');
    const directive = probe.injector.get(ref);
    directive.control.setValue(item.val);
});
```

As the other answer, only works for *debug* builds.