# How to trick Angular to believe text input was filled

Tags: javascript, angular

I am messing with an external Angular app that I do not control. The app has several input fields and I want to fill them in programatically

```
document.querySelector('input[name=userEmail]').value='hello@email.com';
```

The issue is that upon submission, Angular believes the inputs are empty, so I get a client-side validation error.

How can I programmatically change a field of an Angular app from outside the app?

Answer (score 1):

The way you tried to manipulate input is not enough because it is not triggering angular change detection.

Check the accepted answer here:
[How to update a angular 4+ form values using console devtools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973202/how-to-update-a-angular-4-form-values-using-console-devtools)