# Angular 6: Programmatically changing value of input element in production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am using a Angular 6 js script which I purchased without access to the underlying readable code. The js code I can see is webpack. I want to make a few small additions with plain js or jq. Specifically, I want to programmatically set values of input elements. In jq: `$(selector).val(value)`. As I don't have access to the source code, I must add a custom js script to manipulate the input.

This is what I have tried:

- Selecting the element and dispatch a click-keyboardevent to select it. Then I repeatedly fired keyboard events with the characters I wanted to enter as input. As I
  learned from
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent,
  manually firing a keyboard event will not result in the default
  behavior. So this let to nothing.
- Following [How to update a angular 4+ form values using console devtools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973202/how-to-update-a-angular-4-form-values-using-console-devtools) was also a dead end because the script is in production so ng.probe()
  doesn't work.
- I managed to attach listeners to a few custom events that I could distill from the webpack code but none of them got me any further.
- And, of course, I tried all shapes and forms of
  `$(selector).val(value)`, both in jq and in plain js. All to no
  avail.

Any other suggestions how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found this to be working for Angular 12:

```js
const input = document.querySelector(selector);
input.value = value;
input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
```

In jQuery this would be something like:

```js
$(selector).val(value).trigger("input");
```

Comment: Thanks, regapictures, for your help. It does the trick in most cases in Angular 6 (and presumably A7-11) as well.