# Angular: How to get component dependancy via console?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-di

I put focus on component element in dev tools and can do following:

```
 ng.probe($0)
```

to get the special object "**DebugElement**". Now we can get its injector:

```
 ng.probe($0).injector
```

now I would like to get a dependancy that is defined on this component. Dependancy is defined like a class, so I should do something like so:

```
ng.probe($0).injector.get(MyService)
```

BUT! Service is not defined in console scope. 
If I make it a string:

```
 ng.probe($0).injector.get('MyService')
```

obviously it also does not work.

I'm trying to do reverse engineering on [ReflectiveInjector.get](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/di/reflective_injector.ts#L307), but no luck for now. Any ideas?

Comment: @yurzui, will you make it an answer with some explanation? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to pass token to `injector.get` method as it was declared. We can't use string if we declared class as token.

Angular keeps providers declared within component in ngfactory [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/COOorBoKtPHKEx33f0pC?p=preview)

```
function View_App_Host_0(_l) {
  return jit_viewDef0(0,[(_l()(),jit_elementDef1(0,null,null,2,'my-app',[],null,null,
      null,jit_View_App_02,jit__object_Object_3)),jit_providerDef4(4608,null,jit_MyService5,
      jit_MyService5,[]),jit_directiveDef6(49152,null,0,jit_App7,[],null,null)],null,
      null);
}
```

And it uses elementInjector to get dependency.

[image]

`DebugElement` gets information about tokens provided to current node

```
get providerTokens(): any[] {
  const tokens: any[] = [];
  if (this.elDef) {
    for (let i = this.elDef.index + 1; i <= this.elDef.index + this.elDef.childCount; i++) {
      const childDef = this.elView.def.nodes[i];
      if (childDef.flags & NodeFlags.CatProvider) {
        tokens.push(childDef.provider !.token);
      }
      i += childDef.childCount;
    }
  }
  return tokens;
}
```

After we declared provider within `providers` array of component metadata the token becomes available in `providerTokens` array.

So we can get dependency by writing

```
ng.probe($0).injector.get(ng.probe($0).providerTokens
    .find(x => x.name === 'MyService'))
```

See also

- [Trigger Angular change detection from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838568/trigger-angular-change-detection-from-console)

Comment: saw your comment and just thought that I would put an answer in the morning)