# Access angular NgZone instance from window.object

Tags: angular, zone, ngzone

Is it possible to access angular(2+) **ZoneJS instance** *(NgZone)*  **without** injecting
it inside *constructor* like this:

```
...

 const zone = window['<angular zonejs path in window object>']
...
```

For now when I developing my angular library I need to do this:

```
class Test {
 constructor( zone: NgZone ) { initmyplugin(zone); }
}
```

But I don't wanna user to care about initialization of NgZone.

Comment: Also I don't wanna use injector https://angular.io/api/core/Injector to keep library framework independent.

Comment: `ng.coreTokens.NgZone`

Comment: Sorry @yurzui, but this is not an **instance**...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get hold of `NgZone` instance by using the following code:

```
ng.probe(getAllAngularRootElements()[0]).injector.get(ng.coreTokens.NgZone)
```

See also

- [Trigger Angular change detection from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838568/trigger-angular-change-detection-from-console)

Comment: There is a problem with this command when I've got compiled my bundle with: `ng build --aot -prod --no-sourcemap` and `ng.probe(getAllAngularRootElements()[0])` returns **null**. Do you know how to access ngzone in this application mode ?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/blob/master/src/environments/environment.ts#L24-L28 Maybe this can help you