# Trigger change detection in Angular IVY application

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

Before IVY, we could trigger change detection like this, based on [this awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838660/3694288) SO answer:

```js
ng.probe(getAllAngularRootElements()[0]).injector.get(ng.coreTokens.ApplicationRef).tick()
```

The question now is, how do we achieve this in Ivy?

When running in dev mode, and typing `ng` in the console reveals this:

[image]

But I am unsure how to use this to detect changes in the root element?

**workaround**

By injecting the `ChangeDetectorRef` in a given component, i can do the following (where $0 is the previously selected element in the dev tools):

```js
ng.getComponent($0).changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
```

But this is not for the root component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
ng.markDirty($0)
```

Where $0 is the selected element in the devtools panel.

In v9 it's the `applyChanges` method.

Comment: ok, so when doing this programmatically you would then have to query for the root element first, and then `markDirty`? Does markDirty trigger changeDetection, or does it only mark the component for change detection next time it runs?

Comment: It takes a component and triggers change detection.

Comment: I just upgraded to Angular v9 now, and I can't find the method markDirty?

Comment: ng.applyChanges()

Comment: Currently this stackoverflow answer is ranking high for `ng.applyChanges` and it isn't explained well *at all* in the Angular docs. So for people like me that just found `ng.applyChanges()` by itself throws an assertion error - you must provide a component. `ng.applyChanges(ng.getComponent(temp1))` where `temp1` is a DOM element. You can right click on the `app-mycomponent` node in Chrome and select `Store as global variable` to get `temp1` assigned to a component already on the page.